# String Array not Outputting In Reverse

Tags: java, arrays, string

I got a question that went like this;

Create a Java program called Lab2Part4 that contains a method called
outputInReverse. The method must input THREE strings and then output the
three strings in reverse with a space between them, 
e.g.,
`outputInReverse(“The”, “Black” ,“Cat”)` will output `“Cat Black The”` as one string.

I thought of doing a nested for loop where the the original array would override a new array in the reverse order and then print the new array but seem to be messing somewhere

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     String[] ArrayInput = new String[] { "The", "Black", "Cat" };
     outputInReverse(ArrayInput);
}

public static void outputInReverse(String[] FirstOrder) {
     String[] FinalOrder = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};

     for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
         for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
            FinalOrder[j] = FirstOrder[i];
         }
     }
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(FinalOrder));
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you learned how to debug java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the same values to all the elements of the `FinalOrder` array in the nested loop.

```
Final order[0]: Cat 
Final order[1]: Cat 
Final order[2]: Cat 
Final order[0]: Black   
Final order[1]: Black   
Final order[2]: Black   
Final order[0]: The 
Final order[1]: The 
Final order[2]: The
```

Try this:

```
public static void outputInReverse(String[] FirstOrder) {
    String[] FinalOrder = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            FinalOrder[j] = FirstOrder[i];
            j++;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(FinalOrder));
}
```

Output:

```
[Cat, Black, The]
```

Answer (score 0):

The nested loop doesn't work in a way you have used it in that case.

If we would try to understand step-by-step what is happening inside those loops:

```
for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
        FinalOrder[j] = FirstOrder[i];
    }
}
```

Then the operations performed would look like that:

```
FinalOrder[0] = FirstOrder[2]
FinalOrder[1] = FirstOrder[2]
FinalOrder[2] = FirstOrder[2]
FinalOrder[0] = FirstOrder[1]
FinalOrder[1] = FirstOrder[1]
FinalOrder[2] = FirstOrder[1]
FinalOrder[0] = FirstOrder[0]
FinalOrder[1] = FirstOrder[0]
FinalOrder[2] = FirstOrder[0]
```

In case of such operations your output would be: `"The The The"` as the first element of the `FirstOrder` array is assigned to all indexes of the `FinalOrder` array as last 3 operations.

So you cannot use the loops like that to achieve what you want to achieve.
To do that I would rather do something like:

```
for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    FinalOrder[2 - i] = FirstOrder[i];
}
```

Additionally, you don't need to fill in the `FinalOrder` array with elements. You can just create an empty array of size 3, like:

`String[] FinalOrder = new String[3];`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code with a java compiler with a slight modification by adding a print statement:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] ArrayInput = new String[] { "The", "Black", "Cat" };

        outputInReverse(ArrayInput);

    }




    public static void outputInReverse(String[] FirstOrder) {
        String[] FinalOrder = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};

        for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
                FinalOrder[j] = FirstOrder[i];
                System.out.println(FinalOrder[j]);
            
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(FinalOrder));
    }

}
```

The output looks like this:

> Cat
>
> Cat
>
> Cat
>
> Black
>
> Black
>
> Black
>
> The
>
> The
>
> The
>
> [The, The, The]

The intuition:

In the inner loop, you are actually assigning each of the `FinalOrder` with the same value `FirstOrder[i]`, so to eliminate it, you can either use a `break` statement, or the simple code by Hulya.

You can easily learn to debug by using the print statement :)